# Vue-Router: How to always replace when navigating away from specific route without infinitely redirecting

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I have a component in which I create a resource (a message) on the server, but delete it, when you navigate away from the current route.

I'm trying to always `replace` the route instead of pushing to router's history, so that you can't accidentally navigate back to the page with the messageId, because it will be deleted by that point.

I played around for a while with my router.beforeEach() which already handles the deletion of the resource and such. But when I try to replace it by using `next()` or even without next, returning `{ ...to, replace: true}` where I'd normally `return true`, then I get infinite redirects.

I understand now, that returning a `RouteLocationNormalized` (which is `to`'s type) then a new navigation is triggered with the SAME `from`. So that explains the infinite redirect.

Now my question I suppose is: How do I replace, without redirecting?

Here's my code:

```js
// Prevent navigation
onMounted(() => {
    createRouterHook()
})
let removeRouterHook: () => void | null = () => null
onUnmounted(() => {
    removeRouterHook()
})
async function createRouterHook() {
    removeRouterHook = router.beforeEach(async () => {
        if (!message.value) {
            return true
        }

        // Delete message if it is and was empty
        if (wasEmpty && isEmpty()) {
            await deleteMessage(message.value)
            return true
        }

        // Allow navigation if message was not changed
        if (!meta.value.dirty) {
            return true
        }

        const response = await show({
            type: "options",
            optionsType: "button",
            title: "Are you sure you want to leave?",
            description: `Unsaved changes will be deleted.`,
            options: [
                { text: "Save Draft", value: 0 },
                { text: "Discard Draft", value: 1 },
            ],
        })

        switch (response) {
            case 0:
                await saveMessage()
                return true
            case 1:
                if (wasEmpty) {
                    await deleteMessage(message.value)
                }
                return true
            default:
                return false
        }
    })
}
```